# trouble finding Ubuntu

Tags: startup

Installation went fine on my old tower pc.  I replaced windows xp with Ubuntu 12.4 and continued on with the reboot.  The trouble is that nothing appears upon start up.  dos works through the initial start up but the ubuntu operating system will not turn on.  did I miss something?  I thought I followed the step by step process fine.  could it be that the address is missing from dos to ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of ubuntu. You are very new to ubuntu, so please refer the ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS [installation guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)   and redo the installation. It will surely work.

Comment: I never knew I had trouble finding Ubuntu until the first time we met ...

Comment: @cxrodgers It is not sure everybody faces trouble for the first time in ubuntu....but some people need assistance in ubuntu the very first time...!